# Evaluation code understanding in wide and deep model of tensorflow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

I'm doing some research on the wide and deep model developed by Google. And I got 2 questions on the training and evaluation code fragment. ([Complete code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep_run_loop.py#L96-L120) see here):

```
  train_hooks = hooks_helper.get_train_hooks(
      flags_obj.hooks, model_dir=flags_obj.model_dir,
      batch_size=flags_obj.batch_size, tensors_to_log=tensors_to_log)

  # Train and evaluate the model every `flags.epochs_between_evals` epochs.
  for n in range(flags_obj.train_epochs // flags_obj.epochs_between_evals):
    model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, hooks=train_hooks)

    results = model.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

    # Display evaluation metrics
    tf.logging.info('Results at epoch %d / %d',
                    (n + 1) * flags_obj.epochs_between_evals,
                    flags_obj.train_epochs)
    tf.logging.info('-' * 60)


    for key in sorted(results):
      tf.logging.info('%s: %s' % (key, results[key]))


    benchmark_logger.log_evaluation_result(results)


    if early_stop and model_helpers.past_stop_threshold(
        flags_obj.stop_threshold, results['accuracy']):
      break
```

So my questions:

1. default setting for `epochs_between_evals` is 2, but how is it possible for evaluating 1 epoch after training for every 2 epochs? Apparently there is one `model.evaluate()` after every `model.train()`, isn't it?
   Perhaps the `train_hooks` controls that in `model.train()` to break every 2 epochs, but the parameters of `train_hooks` don't include `num_epochs` or `epochs_between_evals`. I'm a bit confused.
2. What does `model.evaluate()` actually do? As I check the source code, it seems it's just a forwarding pass to get evaluation outputs. Any other work done behind the scene?